# how to add radio button in recycle view?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, radio-button, android-recyclerview

I want to add radio button each item in recycle view. can anyone know how to add radio button in recycle view?

This is my recycler view:

[image: This is my recycler view]

I want this

[image: and this is i want to be]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".UserSearchActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:theme="@style/SearchView"
            app:defaultQueryHint="@string/hint_type_name_or_email" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your list_item xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add separate `layout xml` file for `recycler view` items and include `radio button`.

for example in **recycler_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="New RadioButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then update the item vales by using the `recycler list view adapter`.

Comment: Add custom recycler view adapter class and handle the radio button visibility in adapter class.